# Ubuntu 14.04 booting system without full network configuration

Tags: 14.04, boot, wireless, networking, network-manager

I've messed around with my network settings lately and I have no idea what I've done, but now my wifi doesn't seem to be working right. When I boot my system up I get the message

> booting system without full network configuration

I tried following the guide [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259942/booting-system-without-full-network-configuration) to reset my /etc/network/interfaces file, and now I get the same message at boot but my network manager doesn't even turn on when I login.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm also facing this issue after upgraded to 14.10.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the case you can try with some changes,

sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

After this press CtrlX and N to remove the changes. After doing this it is must to restarts the system.

sudo reboot

Hope this helps.

Comment: unfortunately this didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: `Ctrl+X` just exit `nano`